# Need to parse JSON file from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: json, parsing, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am generating a json output file through Jenkins pipeline script. I need to parse JSON file through Jenkins Pipeline script further to get the key attributes like total incidents, total occurrences, type,policy and filenames of each from below json file.

JSON File,

```
{
    "id": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample",
    "type": "path_scan",
    "entities_with_incidents": [{
        "mode": "FILE",
        "filename": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample/fakesecret.txt",
        "incidents": [{
            "policy": "Secrets detection",
            "occurrences": [{
                "match": "234ae*****************5q345",
                "type": "apikey",
                "line_start": 2,
                "line_end": 2,
                "index_start": 22,
                "index_end": 49,
                "pre_line_start": 2,
                "pre_line_end": 2
            }],
            "type": "Generic High Entropy Secret",
            "validity": "no_checker",
            "ignore_sha": "16b4ab506f666f1d58d7f0b70c65e8036d0922c59023f6815b832b6d6465e670",
            "total_occurrences": 1
        }],
        "total_incidents": 1,
        "total_occurrences": 1
    }, {
        "mode": "FILE",
        "filename": "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample/config.py",
        "incidents": [{
            "policy": "Secrets detection",
            "occurrences": [{
                "match": "ALKS*************4SDA",
                "type": "apikey",
                "line_start": 2,
                "line_end": 2,
                "index_start": 22,
                "index_end": 43,
                "pre_line_start": 2,
                "pre_line_end": 2
            }],
            "type": "Generic High Entropy Secret",
            "validity": "no_checker",
            "ignore_sha": "7ef2d76f21eacc87dbca2de386bebb2b7cf114d6bc5418ba7a36ef5084119054",
            "total_occurrences": 1
        }],
        "total_incidents": 1,
        "total_occurrences": 1
    }],
    "total_incidents": 2,
    "total_occurrences": 2,
    "secrets_engine_version": "2.81.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `readJSON` step (works for reading json files or strings).
It will parse json, and you will be able  to access attributes by names or indexes.

This is the documentation for it: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python to load the json.txt file and convert it to dictionary

```
import json
 
with open('json.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(data["type"]) # path_scan will be printed
```